# WIN10_64bit Unable to find an entry point named 'InterlockedIncrement' in DLL 'kernel32.dll'.'

Tags: .net, vb.net, sqlite

I know its asked before, but I have tried to solve with their answers, but dosnt work

my Os is win10 64bit, nisual studio 2017,

Unable to find an entry point named 'InterlockedIncrement' in DLL 'kernel32.dll'.'

I get this error

I connected to OBDC 32 bit which is located in folder "System64", the connection is successful but still cant run

```
    Imports System.Data.Odbc
'Imports Microsoft.Data.Odbc

    Dim conn As OdbcConnection
            conn = New OdbcConnection("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER==WINDOWS-N4FBG97;UID=sa;PWD=mypassword;DATABASE=master;")
            conn.Open()
```

Comment: Since this is SQL Server, why not use the native provider SQLClient?

Comment: I tried, but still show me "'[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified'
"
Actually this is project I downloaded from internet,
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Oh9Uz4sBtRRUVlNkdKdlplczQ/edit

I did not how to open DB, I have been trying many ways,

Comment: Well, the only way i could think of to help was to download from the link you provided. The code seems to be using an SQL OLEDB provider. It is ADODB not ADO.net. Did you get the database because I didn't see one. Do you have SQL Server on your development machine. Is the DB installed there? The little bit of code I looked at was not very good.